# Linq to SQL using multiple DataContexts in a single query

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have this Linq to SQL query sequence that is basically returning a search on a table called PROJECTS. and I'm taking advantage of the deferred execution to slowly build it up.

```
var query = from p in objDBContext.PROJECTs
where (p.PROVIDER_ID == cwForm.productForm) 
select p; 

query = from p in query
where p.SubmittedDate >= cwForm.beginDateForm
select p;
```

I wrote a few SQL functions that return scalar values and table values as helper function because LINQ doesn't support `ISDATE()` or full text search. they are in the same .dbml file as the `Projects` table.

So now I have:

```
var dateQuery = from d in objDBContext.ISDATE   
select d;
//returns a bool

var ftsQuery = from f in objDBContext.FullTextSearch
select f;
//returns a valued-table with the primary keys of hits with fulltextsearch
```

My question is, how do I use these new objDBContexts on the original query p? I'm also interested in figuring out how to map an executequery() back into the original query.

Something like:

```
query = from p in query
        from d in dateQuery
        from f in ftsQuery
where d.ISDATE(p.Field1) &&  f.FullContextSearch(searchString)    

    select p;
```

I hope that makes sense. I've got a few types mismatched errors and have tried googling for a while but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have defined all your methods on the context class, use the same instance for all three:

```
var query = from p in objDBContext.Projects where
    p.PROVIDER_ID == cwForm.productForm 
    && objDBContext.ISDATE(p.Field1)
    && objDBContext.FullTextSearch(searchString)
        //assuming FullTextSearch returns boolean
    select p
```

if FullTextSearch doesn't return boolean, you need to build an expression that does. Like if it returns IList, you could do `objDBContext.FullTextSearch(searchString).Contains(p)`

Though keep in mind what you're trying to do will cause three round-trips to the database no matter which way you cut it. It might be better just to hand-craft your SQL in this case. LINQ to SQL cannot, and is not intended to, replace SQL 100% of the time.

Comment: thanks Rex, what would be the overhead cost of those SQL? i really like the simplicity and cleanliness of building dynamic SQL queries using LINQ2SQL. and my FullTextSearch returns a valued-table with the index keys of the rows that matches the searchString. would a Join be most efficent here?

Comment: The individual cost overhead is not especially large I guess. It's difficult to say without being more familiar with your application. However, when a question of performance is raised, the number of round-trips to SQL is always one of the first things to look at.